# build a const generic clamp function

Tags: generics, rust, traits

So I have const clamp function for both usize and f32. The logic is simple: it does nothing but comparing `val` with `low` and `high` then returning the suitable value within the range:

```rust
// you might have to switch up to nightly build:
// $ rustup default nightly

#![feature(const_trait_impl)]
#![feature(const_fn_floating_point_arithmetic)]
pub const fn usize_clamp(val: usize, low: usize, high: usize) -> usize {
    if val < low {
        return low;
    }
    if val > high {
        return high;
    }
    return val;
}

pub const fn f32_clamp(val: f32, low: f32, high: f32) -> f32 {
    if val < low {
        return low;
    }
    if val > high {
        return high;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Now I hope to merge them into 1:

```rust
pub const fn clamp<T: PartialOrd>(val: T, low: T, high: T) -> T {
    if val < low {
        return low;
    }
    if val > high {
        return high;
    }
    return val;
}
```

The compiler tells me to restrict the bound on `T` by adding `~const std::cmp::PartialOrd`, so I add it:

```rust
pub const fn clamp<T: PartialOrd + ~ const PartialOrd>(val: T, low: T, high: T) -> T {
    if val < low {
        return low;
    }
    if val > high {
        return high;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Then it says

```
~const can only be applied to `#[const_trait]` traits
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. In general, generic `const` functions are a half-baked feature that is expected to change before stabilization and it is not yet clear what its final shape will be.